# What is default admin for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, database-administration

Workbench is MySQL default. Correct me if I'm wrong. I dont believe SQLite has it own default admin. Is there any recommendation for the admin?

Answer (score 2):

Theres not much to administer in a SQLite DB. There are no users, extra databases, or even any  server settings to speak of. I would use a generic data modeling tool to create my table structures and relations then use the sqlite command line tool to execute the create table scripts. Once your tables are in place then use whatever tool or api you were going to use anyways to interact with the database.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good experience with the Firefox add-on [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817/) - although it's primarily intended to work with FF's SQLite databases, it is usable for unrelated SQLite databases.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite comes with a command-line client.  This is the default administration client for SQLite.